# Distinct Query in nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, nhibernate

I am new in nHibernate and i want to convert following sql query in nHibernate criteria

```
SELECT DISTINCT fReportID, fFiscalYear  
FROM tFCMaster   
WHERE fPropertyID='100'
```

I tried this:

```
Session.CreateCriteria<tFCMaster>().Add(Expression.Eq("fPropertyID", PropertyID))
       .SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property("fFiscalYear")))
       .List<tFCMaster>();
```

help will appreciated.

Comment: could you show is what you have tried, and why i didn't work

Comment: Session.CreateCriteria<tFCMaster>()
                        .Add(Expression.Eq("fPropertyID", PropertyID))          .SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property("fFiscalYear")))
                            .List<tFCMaster>();                                                                                                                       i tried this but it is giving error.

Comment: ok :) you should show that the error is by adding it to your question

Comment: if you want to map the result to tFcMaster, you have to include fPropertyID in your projection (assuming the table has exactly two columns)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

criteria.SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property("Country")));

Best Regards.